# Alpine js remove class while click on body or outside of select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

```
                   <select                     
                        name="country"
                        id="country"
                        :class="{ 'active': isOpen == 1 }"
                        @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
                        @keydown.escape="isOpen = false"
                        class="form-group__input pl-4 rounded-lg  select-triangle-arrow">
                        <option>hello</option
                </select>
```

I successfully added class on click on select . but its not remove while i click on body or outside of select box. Please anyone help me to do this. Thanks

Comment: Please add the JS to the question so we can help you debug it

Answer (score 4):

[Note from Alpine v3.x modifier name have changed](https://alpinejs.dev/upgrade-guide#away-replace-with-outside)

For Alpine.js v3:

You can add another click event handler with the `.outside` modifier.

```
@click.outside="isOpen = false"
```

For Alpine.js v2:

use the `.away` modifier.

```
@click.away="isOpen = false"
```

From the [Docs](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#outside):

> .outside is a convenience helper for listening for a click outside of the element it is attached to.